# Вопросы организации структуры Django-проекта

Tags: django

Всем привет, изучаю программирование и задался вопросом на счет организации файлов в Джанго. Для примера приведу Ютуб, тк он использует Django. В нем есть отдельные страницы "Главная", "Shorts", "Подписки", куча функций и тп. Каким образом разработчики организовали его структуру: разделили страницы по разным приложениям или все скинули в одно? Или вообще создали для каждой страницы свой проект? Я понимаю, что вероятно это точно не известно, но как бы Вы поступили, будучи разработчиком YouTube?)

Например, внутри джанго-проекта я создал джанго-приложение, в котором разместил все страницы, каждая из которых имеет какой-то простой функционал, и вот вопрос, а правильно ли я сделал? Для данного учебного сайта понятно, что это не важно, но если бы я был в тиме по разработке чего-то сложного, то какой способ мне нужно было бы выбрать?

---

### Для конкретики я сформулировал вопросы:

---

1. Следует ли создавать отдельное Django-приложение/проект для каждой страницы или раздела, или лучше использовать единое приложение для всех страниц?
2. Какие преимущества и недостатки связаны с каждым из этих подходов?

Спасибо за ответ

Comment: если объяснять по простому то в django нужно создавать отдельные приложения, если вам нужно добавить НОВОГО функционала, в примере с YouTube, новым приложением является к примеру меню слева и каждый присутствующий там элемент: "мой канал", "история", "ваши видео" и.т.д; для примера, хоть это и не самый лучший пример, можете посмотреть мой учебный проект на django:
https://github.com/StacLigasfolf/branicalms/tree/main